# How to select values from a table (SQL Server database) into a parameter (Stored Procedure)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to select few values from a table (SQL Server database) into few parameters (Stored Procedure) and here's what I did:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].ValidateStudent
(
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50),
    @Yes_No int OUTPUT,
    @StudentId int OUTPUT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        @Yes_No = COUNT(*)
FROM            Student
WHERE        (UserName = @UserName) AND (Password = @Password)
SELECT        @StudentId = StudentId
FROM            Student
WHERE        (UserName = @UserName) AND (Password = @Password)
```

Since I am not sure whether it is the right way to achieve what I have mentioned, I need to know few things:

1. Is it syntactically valid to select 2 values in 2 select statements as in the query above inside 1 stored procedure?
2. Is the way I have written the query to select values from table into parameter is valid or will work?

Please tell me if the above query is valid and if not then suggest me with the valid query for the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just let StudentId be null if it doesn't exist, i.e. `SET @StudentId = (SELECT StudentId FROM Student WHERE ...)`. Or if you also want the flag `SET @Yes_No = CASE WHEN @StudentId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate both parameter values with one `SELECT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].ValidateStudent
(
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50),
    @Yes_No int OUTPUT,
    @StudentId int OUTPUT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        @StudentId = StudentId, @Yes_No = COUNT(1)
FROM            Student
WHERE        (UserName = @UserName) AND (Password = @Password)
GROUP BY StudentId
```

That said, wouldn't the value of @Yes_No always be 1, unless you have more than one student with the same `UserName` and `Password`?

Comment: I think @Yes_No is used to indicate whether a student exists with the given username and password - if not, then value would be set to 0

Comment: No, the value of @Yes_No wouldn't always be 1 since COUNT() returns 1 when the condition is true and 0 if the condition is false.